# Non-minified version of Twitter javascript files? (e.g. widgets.js)

Tags: twitter, unminify

Is there a place where Twitter publishes non-minified versions of their javascript files for their buttons and widgets?

E.g. http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js the minified version.